# How to import email contacts from various email service providers in a website?

Tags: javascript, email, contacts

I am trying to implement a email invitation tool that can be used by a member in my website and invite his contacts over email to review blogs. But I am not able to find a way to design the tool for multiple email service providers so that I can reach out to a maximum crowd. I have experimented with [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) in JavaScript and I works good but I want some directive to do the same for other email providers too. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try OpenInviter ([www.openinviter.com](http://www.openinviter.com)). They provide an API for PHP to import email contacts from several email providers. Check their demo here ([openinviter.com/demo/](http://openinviter.com/demo/))

GeekTantra

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but I am looking for something in javascript or better in asp.net.

Comment: OpenInviter is an open API and can be used with absolutely any language.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that describes a few options...

http://hellblogger.com/2011/08/plaxo-api-contact-importer-widget-alternative/

- Open Inviter
- Contactsimporter.net
- Cloudsponge
- Janrain Engage