# Access contacts from various email sites

Tags: asp.net, .net

How can i access various contacts associated with my any of gmail/yahoo/rediff account Or can i load inbox from there to my website. Just like gmail imports contacts from others sites or loading emails from other sites. I gone through thread [How to import email contacts from various email service providers in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932590/how-to-import-email-contacts-from-various-email-service-providers-in-a-website) but could not find way to use this API.

Thanks

Comment: One think i forgot to mention,  this is , net application so please provide the solutions which adheres to .net platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the general API [here](http://openinviter.com/download.php). Assuming you have some basic php understanding you simply use the classes within the API to get the list of emails. check out the documentation for gmail [here](http://openinviter.com/documentation/OpenInviter/gmail.html).

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have downloaded plugin for gmail. Its a .php file. How can i use this file in asp.net application